# Sqlx "missing destination name" for struct tag through pointer

Tags: go, sqlx

I have a model like this:

```
type Course struct {
    Name string `db:"course_name"`
}

type Group struct {
    Course *Course
}
type Groups []Group
```

And when i try to do sqlx.Select for Groups with a query like this:

```
SELECT c.name as course_name FROM courses as c;
```

I get

> missing destination name course_name in *main.Groups

error.

What is the issue with this code?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `sqlx.Select` when you are selecting multiple rows and you want to scan the result into a slice, as is the case for your query, otherwise use `sqlx.Get` for a single row.

In addition, you can't scan directly into a `Group` struct because none of its fields are tagged (unlike the `Course` struct), and the `Course` field isn't embedded.

Try:

```
course := Course{}
courses := []Course{}

db.Get(&course, "SELECT name AS course_name FROM courses LIMIT 1")
db.Select(&courses, "SELECT name AS course_name FROM courses")
```

Comment: You don't need to tag every field in order to use it with sqlx as long as there is no ambiguity. I still don't understand why my code (in the question) doesn't work. Sqlx can't read struct tags through pointers? Sqlx can't scan values to structs through pointers?

Comment: Do you need to tag the struct Course itself (as opposed to just the Names field)? ie: `db:"courses"` after the `}` of your Course struct?

Comment: The error message explains exactly what the issue is: the `Group` struct has no field tagged `course_name`, therefore you can't scan into it. Either tag an appropriate field in the `Group` struct as `course_name`, or scan directly into a `Course` struct instead.

Comment: If i have to scan directly than i don't need sqlx because it's like plain database/sql works.

Answer (score 2):

I changed `Course *Course` to `Course Course` - no effect.
When i made it embedded like this:

```
type Group struct {
    Course
}
```

it worked.

This is also valid:

```
type Group struct {
    *Course
}
```

Looks like sqlx doesn't understand anything except embedded fields.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so when you are using an embbeded struct with Sqlx, capitalization is important, at least in my case.

You need to refer to the embedded struct in your sql, like so:

`select name as "course.name" from courses...`

Notice that `course` is lower case and the naming involves a dot/period between table and column.

Then your `Get` or `Select` should work just fine.